# Automating xctrace stuck on "Stopping recording..."

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm using xctrace to automate performance testing to capture hangs in an iOS app. The tests consist of these steps:

- Run our UI tests with xcodebuild
- For each UI test case

  - Pause app runner
  - Start xctrace in a subshell and wait until it's recording
  - Continue the app runner
  - Wait until the UI test is done
  - Stop xctrace
  - Wait for recording to be saved
  - Continue with next test

This works great, but around once every twenty runs, xctrace does not exit, but seems to be stuck on `Stopping recording...`

I'm wondering what is causing this and how to fix it.

Starting xctrace with:

```bash
xcrun xctrace record \
    --device <device> \
    --attach <pid|name> \
    --template <path|name> \
    --time-limit 5m \
    --no-prompt \
    --output recording.trace \
    >> trace.log \
    &
    2>&1 \

xctracePID=$!
```

And stopping it later with:

```
kill -INT $xctracePID 2>/dev/null
wait $xctracePID 2>/dev/null         # Sometimes gets stuck on 'Stopping recording...'
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for the above, I am also facing issue with saving the xctrace.

Comment: Nope, I  did not..